# Electric flux through Metallic sheet

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

What is the electric flux through a metallic sheet placed in uniform electric field. Does electric flux imply lines that actually pass through the interiors of a surface or just strike the surfaces and leave ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You may consider adding what you thought and did about the question because it seems like it is a part of homework or an exam.

Comment: I feel like  electrix flux implies the lines that actually pass through the interiors and not just strike the surface and leave from the the other end as in the case of conductors where the no electric field lines exist between the charged ends.And this isn't a homework question btw. Peace :)

Answer (score 1):

For the electrostatic case, it is assumed that after applying the external field we wait for it to equilibrate because the external field induces an electrostatic field on the metal sheet and due to the induction the external field exactly canceled out the interior but the sheet has no thickness external field causes accumulation of charges on the surface of the sheet (but as you can guess due to the zero thickness there are some physical problems). Also, for the field lines, the external field is canceled out in the interior, if the sheet has thickness but it doesn't have and to find the superposed field you can solve Laplace's equation for the regime you want to look at.

Comment: So electric flux is basically the electric field lines that pass through the metallic surface ( even through interiors) but becomes zero after some time due to charge separation leading to zero electric field inside the interiors ?

Comment: Yes, you are right it can pass through materials and the final result of the electric field is a superposition of both external and induction so the zero-field in some region actually means that the external cancelation due to induction.